# Using where clauses to query from array column in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, where-clause

I have an array column in my database, How can I use where clauses to query from it in Laravel? something like :

```
Model::where( 'languages.en', 'term' )->get()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "array column" exactly? Are you storing json data in the column? If so, is it a json field or a text field?

Comment: What is the column name as well as we would like to see table structure.

Comment: if you mean json column you should do this 'languages->en'

Comment: Do you have any more information you can share with us?

Answer (score 0):

You can user something like this:

```
$cats = DB::table('categories')->where('id',1)->get();

foreach($cats as $cat) {
    echo "ID: " . $cat->id . ", ";
    echo "Name: " . $cat->name . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your column values are serialized and using Laravel attribute casting. you could do a like search on that serialized column to match between a key and value.

```
Model::where('language', 'like', '%"en":term%');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
$langs= DB::table('languages')->where('id','=',1)->get();
OR
$langs= Languages::where('id','=',1)->get();
```

In your blade

```
@foreach($langs as $lang)
{{$lang->id}}
{{$lang->name}}
@endforeach
```